# Ajax Pagination

Tags: pagination, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to use [this script](https://github.com/reusserdesign/ExpressionEngine-Ajax-Pagination) to AJAX load paginated entries in EE. There may be a far simpler way to do it though.

This script works, but replaces the current 10 entries with the next 10 entries, but instead I would like the next 10 entries to be appended to the list.

Also, clicking the Show More button should keep adding the next 10 '`<article>`'s and then the Show More button should disappear once there are no more to show.

```
<section id="articles">
    {exp:channel:entries channel="page" sort="asc" orderby="title" limit="10" paginate="bottom" dynamic="no"}
        <article>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            {page_summary}
        </article>
        {paginate}
            {pagination_links}
                <ul class="pagination">
                    {next_page}
                        <li><a href="{pagination_url}">Show More</a></li>
                    {/next_page}
                </ul>
            {/pagination_links}
        {/paginate}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</section>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function(a) {
    a.fn.pager = function(b) {
        var d = "#" + a(this).attr("id");
        var c = {
            link: ".pagination a",
            pull: d + " > *",
            loaderID: "loader",
            scrollTo: "body",
            fadeSpeed: 100,
            fadeOpacity: 0.5
        };
        var b = a.extend(c, b);
        a(b.link).live("click", function(g) {
            g.preventDefault();
            var f = a(this).attr("href");
            a(d, function() {
                a(d).fadeTo(b.fadeSpeed, b.fadeOpacity);
                a(d).after('<i id="' + b.loaderID + '" style="display: none;"></i>');
                a("#" + b.loaderID).fadeIn(b.fadeSpeed)
            }).load(f + " " + b.pull, function() {
                a(d).fadeTo(b.fadeSpeed, 1);
                a(window).scrollTop(a(b.scrollTo).position().top);
                a("#" + b.loaderID).fadeOut(b.fadeSpeed, function() {
                    a("#" + b.loaderID).remove()
                })
            })
        })
    }
})(jQuery);
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#articles').pager();
});
</script>
```

I wondered if anyone might be able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I wouldn't even mess with that plugin since that's what it's supposed to do. Just do a simple ajax call and append the data like this. Note the move of `#articles` to the main template, and `paginate_base` parameter in the embed template.

Main Template

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <section id="articles">
            {embed="main/embed"}
        </section>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //set the click listener on pagination
                paginationClickHandler();
            });

            function paginationClickHandler() {
                $(".pagination li a").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();

                    //link to the next set of articles
                    var href = $(this).attr("href");

                    //get new articles and pagination
                    $.get(href, {}, function(data){
                        //remove existing pagination
                        $(".pagination").remove();

                        //add new articles and pagination links
                        $("#articles").append(data);

                        //disable pagination click listener
                        $('.pagination li a').off('click');

                        //set new click listener with new pagination links
                        paginationClickHandler();
                    });
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Main/Embed Template

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="page" sort="asc" orderby="title" limit="10" paginate="bottom" paginate_base="main/embed" dynamic="no"}
        <article>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            {page_summary}
        </article>
        {paginate}
            {pagination_links}
                <ul class="pagination">
                    {next_page}
                        <li><a href="{pagination_url}">Show More</a></li>
                    {/next_page}
                </ul>
            {/pagination_links}
        {/paginate}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks man. I just had to modify a little to bring the jQuery script in before the embed to make it work.

Comment: Hi doubleplusgood, can you please illustrate how you got this working. I can't seem to get my head around it and when I use the code above it just works like the normal pagination. Thanks :)

Comment: Brandon's solution works great but... when I press the button once only. 10 items have been added to the current list but the second click is refreshing the page and sending to .../P30. So the question is: how to add more items clicking more than one time?

Comment: Hey Bosmi, I've updated the script to have the click listener in the parent, which should allow multiple "loads" of articles. I didn't test this, but I think it should work. I also added some comments to show what I'm doing in the jQuery.